# UICollectionView custom layout footer view not sticking to the bottom of collection view

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm following [this guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/392-uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest) to make Pinterest-like collection view layout, it worked fine until I wanted to add a footer view to it.

In the `prepare()` method I added the following code:

```swift
// Add Attributes for section footer
let footerAtrributes = UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes(forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionView.elementKindSectionFooter, with: IndexPath(item: 0, section: 0))
footerAtrributes.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: collectionView.bounds.maxY, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: myFooterHeight)
cache.append(footerAtrributes)
```

After calling `collectionView:viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:atIndexPath:`, I'm able to add the footer to the collectionView but it is not in the correct y position.

Like this:

[image: like this]

It will crash if scroll further more since I called `collectionView.reloadData()`. The error I am receiving is:

> layout attributes for supplementary item at index path changed without invalidating the layout.

I believe that the `y position` is not correct but I don't really know what to put there.

How can I set it to the right position as the `UICollectionView` updates (load more items)?

Comment: Is the bottom of your collection view pinned to something?

Comment: @Adrian Yes, it's pinned to the bottom edge of the superview

Answer (score -1):

this error:

> layout attributes for supplementary item at index path changed without
>   invalidating the layout.

is cause of set the Layout for the **FooterView**

so you must do *Layout* for the **View**

this is an example of my **CollectionView**

```
let historyCollection: UICollectionView = {
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.sectionInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 10, right: 0)
        layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 20
        layout.scrollDirection = .vertical

        let historyCollection = UICollectionView(frame: CGRect.zero, collectionViewLayout: layout)
        historyCollection.register(CodiHistoryCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "history")
        historyCollection.register(fooderSection.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footer")
        historyCollection.isScrollEnabled = true
        historyCollection.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        historyCollection.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return historyCollection
    }()
```

so after you name your **Identifier**

```
UICollectionElementKindSectionFooter, withReuseIdentifier: "footer"
```

you had to place what it's going to be inside the "FooterView" i did in my Controller Class

```
import UIKit

class fooderSection: UICollectionReusableView {

        let checkBtn: UIButton = {
            let checkBtn  = UIButton(type: .custom)
            checkBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "loadMoreIcon"), for: .normal)
            checkBtn.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFit
            checkBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return checkBtn
        }()



    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

        override init(frame: CGRect) {
            super.init(frame: frame)

            self.addSubview(checkBtn)

            //this is how it's going to show in the bottonVIEW
just play while this values
            NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
                checkBtn.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerXAnchor),
                checkBtn.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.centerYAnchor),
                checkBtn.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70),
                checkBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 70)
                ])

        }
    }
```

also you had to set a ***reference*** size for the FooterView

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForFooterInSection section: Int) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: interface.frame.height * 0.1)
    }
```

Comment: I'm using custom layout, not UICollectionViewFlowLayout()

Comment: @yellowdogpee just move the x OR y where you wanted to be in the view